# hadoop datanode, resourcemanager, nodemanager not starting

Tags: hadoop

i am using hadoop and it was working fine. but today when i restarted the server, now jps command is showing something like

```
9801 NameNode
12142 Jps
10207 SecondaryNameNode
```

i have reconfigured the files again from http://pingax.com/install-hadoop2-6-0-on-ubuntu/

Note :- after restart the server name has change from

```
hduser@hadoop-master:
```

to

```
hduser@silp-ProLiant-DL360-Gen9:
```

is there any problem due to server name or something else?

after start-all.sh command it is showing

```
hduser@silp-ProLiant-DL360-Gen9:~$ start-all.sh
This script is Deprecated. Instead use start-dfs.sh and start-yarn.sh
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: starting namenode, logging to   /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-namenode-silp-ProLiant-DL360-Gen9.out
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-datanode-silp-ProLiant-DL360-Gen9.out
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-secondarynamenode-silp-ProLiant-  DL360-Gen9.out
starting yarn daemons
starting resourcemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-hduser-resourcemanager-silp-ProLiant-DL360-Gen9.out
localhost: starting nodemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-hduser-nodemanager-silp-ProLiant-DL360-Gen9.out
hduser@silp-ProLiant-DL360-Gen9:~$ jps
15408 Jps
14724 SecondaryNameNode
14316 NameNode
```

Please help

NOTE- /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-datanode-silp-ProLiant-DL360-Gen9.out is showing :

```
ulimit -a for user hduser
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 127536
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 127536
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Comment: what are the service logs saying? https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.3.0-Win/bk_HDP_Install_Win/content/ref-8896fe3b-8788-4a88-b7cc-d77d6f2481fc.1.html

Comment: Check for `ERROR` in this file `/usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-datanode-silp-ProLiant-‌​DL360-Gen9.log`!

Comment: Post the `ERROR`s in `/usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-datanode-silp-ProLiant-‌​‌​DL360-Gen9.log` file. Not the `.out` file.